# How to update the Figure attributes (x_range) after the Figure is already created using bokeh 1.4, programatticall?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization, bokeh, pandas-bokeh

I am trying to create a `Bar Chart` here, I already have `figure` object, but want to assign `x_range` later instead of inside `figure object`.

I have tried various techniques shown at the end, I am using `Bokeh 1.4`

```
    def generate_bar_chart(
          self, lst_category,lst_frequency, lst_colors, str_xlabel, str_ylabel, str_plot_title,     
          plot_height=700, plot_width=800, width_bar=0.6):

        try:
            source = ColumnDataSource(
                dict(
                    x=lst_category,
                    values=lst_frequency,
                    color=lst_colors[:len(lst_category)]
                )
            )

            hover_tool = HoverTool(
                tooltips=[("Prod Order", "@x"), ("Frequency", "@values")]
            )

            p = figure(
                x_range=lst_category, # I want to set it programatically afterwards, not here
                title=str_plot_title,
                plot_height=plot_height,
                plot_width=plot_width,
                background_fill_color="#f9f9f9",
            )
            p.add_tools(hover_tool)
            p.vbar(
                x="x",
                top="values",
                width=width_bar,
                source=source,
                line_color="#020B13",
            )
            # p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
            p.y_range.start = 0
            p.x_range.range_padding = 0.2
            p.xaxis.axis_label = str_xlabel
            p.yaxis.axis_label = str_ylabel
            p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1.1
            p.outline_line_color = "#020B13"
            p.xaxis.major_label_text_font_size = "11pt"
            p.yaxis.major_label_text_font_size = "11pt"
            p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "11pt"
            p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "11pt"
            p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_style = "bold"
            p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_style = "bold"
            p.title.text_font_size = "20pt"
            show(p)
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            if hasattr(e, "message"):
                print(e.message)
            else:
                print(e)



 # I want to do like this
    p.x_range = lst_category 

    # Tried with:
    ## Not working
    p.x_range.factors = lst_category 

    # 
    p.x_range=FactorRange(factors=lst_category)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a complete minimal reproducer, the best that can be offered is a demonstration of it working on an unrelated, but complete, toy example, which will hopefully be useful as a reference:

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import FactorRange
from bokeh.plotting import figure

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
counts = [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(fruits=fruits, counts=counts))

p = figure(plot_height=350, toolbar_location=None, x_range=FactorRange())
p.vbar(x='fruits', top='counts', width=0.9, source=source)

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None

p.x_range.factors = fruits
p.y_range.start = 0
p.y_range.end = 9

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, It worked.
I passed x_range = FactorRange() in the method declaration and then implemented by :
p.x_range.factors = listofCategories in the method implementation